# Android PopupWindow Does Not Dismiss

Tags: android, popupwindow, dismiss

I've got the following code that creates a PopupWindow containing an EditText:

```
lbs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            int pWidth = 100;
            int pHeight = 80;
            int vHeight = mView.getHeight();
            int[] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_popup, null, false);
            final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(view, pWidth, pHeight, false);
            pw.setTouchable(true);
            //pw.setFocusable(true);
            pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            pw.setContentView(view);
            pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0]-(pWidth/4), location[1]+vHeight);
            //final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.PopupLayout);

            final EditText input = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.Input);
            input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    Log.i("Focus", "Focus Changed");
                    /*
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                        inputMgr.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                    */

                }
            });
            input.setText(lbs.getText().toString());
            input.requestFocus();
            pw.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    parentActivity.changeWeight(getId, Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString()));
                    Log.i("View Visibility", "" + view.getVisibility());
                }

            });

            pw.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                        Log.i("Background", "Back Touched");
                        pw.dismiss();               
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }   
    });
```

The PopupWindows has a setBackGroundDrawable so that when the user touches outside the window the box should automatically dismiss. I know the box is dismissing because my OnDismiss method runs when I click outside the box, but the actual window does not disappear until I touch twice outside the box and because of that the onDismiss runs twice which I can't have. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I updated my code slightly. If I DO NOT set focus on the popupwindow everything works perfect except for the fact that I cannot get focus on my edittext. If I do setFocusable on the popup then the edittext does not get focus right away and I have to double click to remove it.

Comment: try this, `pw.setFocusable(true);`

Comment: It's already set. I have to set focusable true on the popup or else I can't focus on my edittext either. I actually figured out a resolution and will post my results.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to know, how to handle click events outside the popup and dismiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be opening more than one popup window. The onTouch method will be called at least for touch down and touch up, and probably a couple touch moves in there too. Try checking for (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) and showing the window only then.

Comment: I had live the same problem and i solve it using above way like that;

fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        popupFinishFragment("Warning","Are you sure to want exit?");
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

Answer (score 1):

Your popupwindow does not get a context of parent activity.
Try to make like this instead of "final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(view, pWidth, pHeight, false);"

```
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
pw.setContentView(view);
pw.setHeight(pHeight);
pw.setWidth(pWidth);
pw.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: This is simply not true. PopupWindow needs an activity context.

Comment: you can give it a Base Context too with `Activity.getBaseContext()` in the `PopUpWindow` constructor. This also helps because if you pass a reference to an activity which has overriden `onBackPressed()` then the `PopUpWindow` will not dismiss with the back button's press or pressing on any place on the screen.